# Email is opened in an external program when I try to send it

Tags: email, mu4e, openwith

When I compose an email with message (via mu4e or otherwise), and include an attachment for a LibreOffice document, I can't send the message. When I try to send it, instead of having the normal response - messages indicating that the message is getting sent, followed by the window closing - what happens instead is that the attachment is opened in LibreOffice!

I can send messages without attachments without a problem, or with attachments of a different filetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to track this down. The problem was due to my using the [openwith](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OpenWith) minor mode. This is normally quite handy. However, when mime messages are generated in Emacs, `openwith` causes the attachment to be opened up with an external program instead of being reinserted as a string.

This is a known issue, and can be fixed with the following:

```el
(add-to-list  'mm-inhibit-file-name-handlers 'openwith-file-handler)
```